# AssertionError in spacy CLI train NER

Tags: command-line-interface, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I try to train my own NER model. I use CLI train comand and I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 
193, in _run_module_as_main
"main", mod_spec)
 File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 
 85, in run_code
 exec(code, run_globals)
 File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
 packages\spacy_main.py", line 31, in 
 plac.call(commands[command])
 File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
 packages\plac_core.py", line 328, in call
 cmd, result = parser.consume(arglist)
 File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
 packages\plac_core.py", line 207, in consume
 return cmd, self.func(*(args + varargs + extraopts), **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
 packages\spacy\cli\train.py", line 107, in train
 train_docs = list(train_docs)
 File "gold.pyx", line 207, in train_docs
 File "gold.pyx", line 221, in iter_gold_docs
 File "gold.pyx", line 235, in spacy.gold.GoldCorpus._make_docs
 File "doc.pyx", line 177, in spacy.tokens.doc.Doc.init
 File "doc.pyx", line 544, in spacy.tokens.doc.Doc.push_back
 AssertionError
```

I use data in spacy JSON format. Does anyone know hoe to solve the issue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Your Environment
spaCy version: 2.0.5
Platform: Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python version: 3.5.4

Comment: What command are you running in the cli? And `spaCy` is usually most happy with `jsonl` format, which is a newline separated doc of json records, is that what you mean by `spacy JSON format`?

Comment: @C.Nivs       _python -m spacy train  [lang] [output_dir] [train_data] [dev_data]_ this a command I'm using and yeah, I mean _jsonl_ I'm also getting an other error, wich I'm also not sure what to do with: _ValueError: Could not find a gold-standard action to supervise the entity recognizer. The transition system has 25 actions._